# How to interpret Mincer equation coefficients

Tags: econometrics, statistics

Consider the Mincer model:
$\log(y)=b_0 + b_1S + b_2E + b_3E^2+u$
where S is schooling, Y is salary (monthly) and E is experience. I want to verify the following statements:

1. The return for 1 extra year of education is $\hat{b_1}*100$%
2. If we knew E (experience) for a particular person, his return for 1 extra year of experience is $\hat{b_2}*E+\hat{b_3}*E^2$. This one I doubt more.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You wouldn't add in $E$ with the coefficients. I'm not sure if there's a clear specification for the return on a year of experience. $b_2, b_3$ both describe the returns on experience, where the $E^2$ coefficient captures the concavity of the earnings function against age, if I recall correctly.

Comment: Do you remember a reference? thank you.

Comment: About 2: Holding $S$ and $u$ fixed, when $E$ increases from $e$ to $e+1$, $\log(y)$ increases by $b_2 + 2b_3 (e+1)$, which is the effect of an increases of $E$. It is thus safe to say that the return on experience is $(b_2 + 2b_3 E)\times 100\%$ if you are happy with replacing $E+1/2$ with $E$.

Comment: Oops. It's $b_2 + 2b_3 (e+1/2)$, not $b_2 + 2b_3 (e+1)$.